# Python alternative to R mutate

Tags: python, r

I want to convert R code into Python. The code in R is

```
df %>% mutate(N = if_else(Interval != lead(Interval) | row_number() == n(), criteria/Count, NA_real_))
```

In Python I wrote the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_table('Fd.csv', sep=',')

for i in range(1,len(df.Interval)-1):
    x = df.Interval[i]
    n = df.Interval[i+1]
    if x != n | x==df.Interval.tail().all():
        df['new']=(df.criteria/df.Count)
    else:
        df['new']='NaN'
df.to_csv (r'dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

However, the output returns all NaNs.

Here is what the data looks like

```
Interval | Count    |   criteria    
0        0               0                             
0        1               0                            
0        2               0                             
0        3               0                             
1        4               1                             
1        5               2                             
1        6               3                            
1        7               4                             
2        8               1                          
2        9               2       
3        10              3
```

and this is what I want to get ( I also need to consider the last line)

```
Interval | Count    |   criteria  |  new

0        0               0                             
0        1               0                            
0        2               0                             
0        3               0       0                      
1        4               1                             
1        5               2                             
1        6               3                            
1        7               4       0.5714                     
2        8               1                          
2        9               2       0.2222 

3        10              3       0.3333
```

If anyone could help find my mistake, I would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Start indexing at 0**

The first thing to note is that Python starts indexing at 0 (in contrast to R which starts at 1). Therefore, you need to modify the index range of your for-loop.

**2. Specify row indices**

When calling

```
df['new']=(df.criteria/df.Count)
```

or

```
df['new']='NaN'
```

you are setting/getting all the values in the "new" column. However, you intend to set the value only in some rows. Therefore, you need to specify the row.

**3. Working example**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Interval"] = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3]
df["Count"] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
df["criteria"] = [0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,1,2,3]
df["new"] = ["NaN"] * len(df.Interval)

last_row = len(df.Interval) - 1
for row in range(0, len(df.Interval)):
    current_value = df.Interval[row]
    next_value = df.Interval[min(row + 1, last_row)]
    if (current_value != next_value) or (row == last_row): 
        result = df.loc[row, 'criteria'] / df.loc[row, 'Count']
        df.loc[row, 'new'] = result
```